# Add OpAmp subcircuit spice model to Altium

Tags: operational-amplifier, altium, spice

I want to add SPICE OpAmp model of Analog devices by .cir extension containing .SUBCKT information to Altium.
I have it's schematic but I don't know how to add it's simulation file to it.
I have double clicked on it then add simulation file, general, SPICE subcircuit, but after that I don't know what must I do.
Although I have found that I can use LTspice for my simulation, but i want to learn it, because I think it can be helpfull for me and other.
[image]

Comment: [Check the Altium documentation.](https://techdocs.altium.com/display/AMSE/Linking+a+Simulation+Model+to+a+Schematic+Component)

Comment: @JRE It's too complicate i can't find my exact instruction.

Comment: Yes, it is complicated.  Your "exact instruction" is that whole page.

Comment: @JRE But it is prety simple in spice!!!!

Comment: Altium isn't (just) spice.

Comment: @JRE I'm w8ing for someone who have done this to explain it simply.